# Data not refreshing after login to homepage in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm saving userdata to `localStorage` in login component and then redirecting to the homepage. In homepage username is not updating on first visit. I have to reload the page. Then data binds to page after refresh. Please help how can I show data on first visit?

below is my homepage code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class Header extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLogin: false,
      isLogout: false,
      user: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const userData = localStorage.getItem("userData");
    const user = JSON.parse(userData);
    this.setState({ user: user });
    if (userData) {
      this.setState({ isLogin: true });
    }
    console.log(userData);
    console.log(user);
  }

  logout = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    localStorage.clear();
    this.setState({ isLogout: true });
  };

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLogin === false || this.state.isLogout === true) {
      return (
        <header
          id="kr-header"
          className="kr-header cd-auto-hide-header kr-haslayout"
        >
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <strong className="kr-logo">
                  <Link to="/">
                    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="company logo here" />
                  </Link>
                </strong>
                <nav className="kr-addnav">
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <Link
                        id="kr-btnsignin"
                        className="kr-btn kr-btnblue"
                        to="login_register"
                      >
                        <i className="icon-smiling-face" />
                        <span>Join Now</span>
                      </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a
                        className="kr-btn kr-btngreen"
                        href="dashboardaddlisting.html"
                      >
                        <i className="icon-plus" />
                        <span>Add Listing</span>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </nav>
                <nav id="kr-nav" className="kr-nav">
                  <div className="navbar-header">
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      className="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                      data-toggle="collapse"
                      data-target="#kr-navigation"
                      aria-expanded="false"
                    >
                      <span className="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                      <span className="icon-bar" />
                      <span className="icon-bar" />
                      <span className="icon-bar" />
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div
                    id="kr-navigation"
                    className="collapse navbar-collapse kr-navigation"
                  >
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <a href="dashboard.html">Dasboard</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </nav>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <header
          id="kr-header"
          className="kr-header cd-auto-hide-header kr-haslayout"
        >
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <strong className="kr-logo">
                  <Link to="/">
                    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="company logo here" />
                  </Link>
                </strong>
                <nav className="kr-addnav">
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <Link
                        id="kr-btnsignin"
                        className="kr-btn kr-btnblue"
                        to="login_register"
                      >
                        <i className="icon-smiling-face" />
                        <span>{this.state.user.user.firstname}</span>
                      </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a
                        className="kr-btn kr-btngreen"
                        href="dashboardaddlisting.html"
                      >
                        <i className="icon-plus" />
                        <span>Add Listing</span>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a onClick={this.logout} className="kr-btn kr-btngreen">
                        <i className="icon-plus" />
                        <span>Logout</span>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </nav>
                <nav id="kr-nav" className="kr-nav">
                  <div className="navbar-header">
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      className="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                      data-toggle="collapse"
                      data-target="#kr-navigation"
                      aria-expanded="false"
                    >
                      <span className="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                      <span className="icon-bar" />
                      <span className="icon-bar" />
                      <span className="icon-bar" />
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div
                    id="kr-navigation"
                    className="collapse navbar-collapse kr-navigation"
                  >
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <a href="dashboard.html">Dasboard</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </nav>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Below is login-register component code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Link,Redirect ,withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Otp from './otp';
import axios from '../api';

export default class LoginRegister extends Component {
    static contextTypes = {
        router: PropTypes.object
      }
    constructor(props,context){
        super(props,context);
        this.state = {
            fname:'',
            lname:'',
            emailaddress:'',
            password:'',
            mobile:'',
            user:'',
            login_pass:'',
            isLogin:false
        }
        this.regi_data = this.regi_data.bind(this);
        this.login_data = this.login_data.bind(this);
        // this.otpModalRef = React.createRef();
    }

    regi_data(e){
        this.setState({[e.target.name] : e.target.value}
        );
    }
    login_data(e){
        this.setState({[e.target.name] : e.target.value})
    }

    // otpModalRef = ({onOpenModal}) => {
    //    this.showModal = onOpenModal;
    // }

    componentDidMount(){
        if (localStorage.getItem('userData')) {
            this.context.router.history.push({
                        pathname:'/',

                    });
        }
    }




    login = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
         axios.post('/api/signin', { 
                        user:this.state.user,
                        password:this.state.login_pass,
                    })
          .then(res => {
                //console.log(res);
                localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(res.data));
                this.context.router.history.push({
                        pathname:'/',

                    });
//                  window.location.reload();
                    this.setState({isLogin: true});
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
          })
    }

    register = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        axios.post('/api/user/add', { 
                        firstname: this.state.fname,
                        lastname:this.state.lname,
                        email:this.state.emailaddress,
                        password:this.state.password,
                        mobile:this.state.mobile 
                    },              
                )
          .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
                // this.showModal();
                 this.context.router.history.push({
                        pathname:'/otp_validate',
                    });            
          }).catch(function(error){
            alert(error.message)
          })
    }
```

Comment: why are you using too many .html files in a Single Page Application? :/

Comment: You are only checking localStorage on `componentDidMount`, so if this component is not unmounted when you go to `/login` it will not be run again. Maybe you can have the `Login` component set state in the parent component instead of localStorage so you don't have to check there?

Comment: @Tholle I didnt get it. Can you please explain more?

Comment: It will be helpful if we know how you did the redirecting too. Maybe you can share the code of the parent component too?

Comment: @wicky I added login register component

Comment: @SagarKodte what about the parent component where you render you `<Header/>` and set your `<Route>`s at? Actaully, like @Tholle suggested, you should probably read from `localStorage` on this component, and then pass the `userData` to all your other child components as a props.

Comment: @SagarKodte do a `console.log` or `console.count` on Header's componentDidMount and you would probably get what the problem is. You would probably notice componentDidMount will not be fired when you redirect

Comment: @SagarKodte you can use `history.push('/toparticularRouter');`

Answer (score 7):

### ISSUE

From the code you have shown above and the issue you are facing, it looks like you have a common component `Header` that is rendered from the parent component of `Login` and `HomePage`, probably from the central App component where you must have also declared the routes for `Login` and `Homepage`. If this is the case, the issue you are facing is that when the App loads for the first time, the Header also loads at that time and its `componentDidMount` method gets called. But since you are not logged in at this time, the header component does not get the user data needed to show the username. Later whenever you perform the actual log in action, store the data in localstorage and redirect to homepage, the header does not get unmounted and remounted because it is outside the scope of these individual `Login` and `Homepage` components, so it's componentDidMount event will not be triggered and there will not be any change detected in the header component.

### FIX

Approach 1: Either create two different `Header` Components, one for logged in state and one for logged out state and place them inside the render methods of `Login` and `HomePage` components respectively. In this case, the above localstorage logic written in `componentDidMount` of these `Header` components shall work properly.

Approach 2: Lift up the user data to the parent of `Header` component and pass the user data as a prop to this component. In this case you can directly use the property in your `Header's` render method.

Comment: Ideally you should make two different headers only if the rendered UI in both these headers is significantly different. If it is almost the same in logged-in and logged-out state, it will be redundant adding two components with same UI. In your case, it is better if you lift up the state to the parent component. Here is a reference for you: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: I didn't check all answers but most of them are actually wrong besides yours. I also having the exact same issue. The problem is like you said, your Header component does not re-render after you logged in or logged out. I am pretty sure second approach is going to work like a charm but I am too lazy to lift my user data up to the parent. The thing is that maybe the third approach could be refresh/redirect the page yet I am not sure if it is the best practice.

Answer (score 1):

try like this in login component

```
login = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.post('/api/signin', {
        user:this.state.user,
        password:this.state.login_pass,
    })
    .then(res => {
        localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(res.data));
        this.context.router.history.push({
            pathname:'/',
            state: { userData: JSON.stringify(res.data) }
        });
        this.setState({isLogin: true});
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    })
}
```

and in homepage check props in componentDidMount

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { userData } = this.props.location.state
    // const user = JSON.parse(userData);
    this.setState({ user: userData });
    if (userData) {
        this.setState({ isLogin: true });
    }
    console.log(userData);
    console.log(user);
}
```

Here you are passing props to home page after login. It should work properly. If not please ask

Comment: it's giving TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined in homepage

Comment: Inside index.js, you should wrap your <App /> component with <BrowserRouter>.

Answer (score 0):

Write these two lines at top of `render()` method. Like this:

```
render() {
  const userData = localStorage.getItem("userData");
  const user = JSON.parse(userData);
  if (user) {
    return (...); // logged in ui
  } else {
    return (...); // logged out ui
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
componentDidMount() {
    const userData = localStorage.getItem("userData");
    const user = JSON.parse(userData);
    this.setState({ user: user });
    if (userData) {
      this.setState({ isLogin: true });
    }
    console.log(userData);
    console.log(user);

    this.setState({})
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach.

```
login = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
     axios.post('/api/signin', { 
                    user:this.state.user,
                    password:this.state.login_pass,
                })
      .then(res => {

            localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(res.data));
            // delay the redirection after udpated the local storage.  
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.context.router.history.push({
              pathname:'/',
              });
              this.setState({isLogin: true});
            }, 500);

      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
      })
}
```

Comment: I dont want to use window.location.reload() because it's reload the page

Comment: What i'm trying to say is delay the this.context.router.history.push by 500 milliseconds will works.

Comment: window.location.relaod() is commented in my code. If I use this. The code works but it's reload the page. give a min I'm adding settimeout to my code

Comment: Yes, I saw it. removed window.location.relaod(). ;)

Comment: HI, not wrkinggg

Answer (score 0):

In your header component, you are deriving the `data` to display from two sources of truth. *LocalStorage* and Components *state*.

This will cause problems because now you have to make sure that the two sources are in sync, which is the problem you are facing currently.

If I look at your `Header` component, you are deriving the state from `LocalStorage`, so if we can get rid of the use of `state` react would always try to render your `header` component and you would avoid your problem of trying to keep the two sources of data in sync.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Header = (props) => {
  let userData = localStorage.getItem("userData");
  if (userData) { // i.e. user IS logged in 
     let user = JSON.parse(userData);
     return ( /* Your code for showing user data. in logout link onClick, clear the local storage */ )
  } else {
     return ( /*Your login/register header*/)
  }

}

export default Header;
```

If you are worried about the performance, first measure the impact. If your userData is not a deeply nested huge json, odds are performance overhead will be negligible. Remember, React calling the `render` method does not mean it will paint the dom.

One assumption I am making: You can rely on `LocalStorage` as the single source of truth. Ideally I would advice on having some cache invalidation logic in there, but it really depends on your usecase and other security measures you have in place.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's running so fast that when you redirect the user to the homepage, after the login, the `userData` was not written to localStorage yet.

So you need to check first if the data was written before the redirect.

```
const asyncLocalStorage = {
    setItem: async function (key, value) {
        await null
        return localStorage.setItem(key, value)
    },
    getItem: async function (key) {
        await null
        return localStorage.getItem(key)
    }
}

asyncLocalStorage.setItem('user', 'data')
  .then( () => asyncLocalStorage.getItem('user') )
  .then( data => {
    console.log('User', data)
    // Redirect ...
  } )
```

Answer (score 0):

Dude your problem is that you have 3 flags that pretty much do the same and you're handling them the wrong way.

for example, this line

`if (this.state.isLogin === false || this.state.isLogout === true)`

will is wrong from the get-go, you initialize both flags as false, so you'll go straight to the else condition.

look at this other line right here

```js
 if (userData) {
  this.setState({ isLogin: true });
 }
```

this code never resets the `isLogout` flag, and the logout method also has issues

```js
logout = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    localStorage.clear();
    this.setState({ isLogout: true });
  };
```

if you login then `isLogin` becomes true and `isLogout` stays false.
if you logout then `isLogout` becomes true and `isLogin` stays true!

at the end of the day, if you don't have userdata, aka your user is null, then you're logged out, no matter how many booleans say the opposite, you have a redundancy of logic issue and you need to simplify your app.

Answer (score 0):

`setState` on `componentWillMount`
everything is same as in your `componentDidMount`, but place it inside of the `componentWillMount`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Header component independent of login and home component, they you should use `getDerivedStateFromProps(props)` instead of `componentDidMount`, as componentDidMount is called only after initial render.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state)** life cycle component as it executes before the initial render and also for each re-rendering. The **componentDidMount()** life cycle method is called after the render method got executed, that too only after the initial render. So setting the state here will be reflected after the component got re-rendered. But the getDerivedStateFromProps is called before the render method is called. You may check the condition there, if there are no changes just return null otherwise update the state there. In getDerived state from props, you may set the state by returning an object. the setState function won't work here, since it is a static method. kindly refer this link https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

Use the code as like below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class Header extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLogin: false,
      isLogout: false,
      user: {}
    };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state){
      const userData = localStorage.getItem("userData");
      const user = JSON.parse(userData);

      if (state.user !== userData){
        return {
            user: user,
            isLogin: true
        }
      }

      return null;
  }

  logout = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    localStorage.clear();
    this.setState({ isLogout: true, isLogin: false });
  };

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLogin === false || this.state.isLogout === true) {
      return (
        <header
          id="kr-header"
          className="kr-header cd-auto-hide-header kr-haslayout"
        >
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <strong className="kr-logo">
                  <Link to="/">
                    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="company logo here" />
                  </Link>
                </strong>
                <nav className="kr-addnav">
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <Link
                        id="kr-btnsignin"
                        className="kr-btn kr-btnblue"
                        to="login_register"
                      >
                        <i className="icon-smiling-face" />
                        <span>Join Now</span>
                      </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a
                        className="kr-btn kr-btngreen"
                        href="dashboardaddlisting.html"
                      >
                        <i className="icon-plus" />
                        <span>Add Listing</span>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </nav>
                <nav id="kr-nav" className="kr-nav">
                  <div className="navbar-header">
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      className="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                      data-toggle="collapse"
                      data-target="#kr-navigation"
                      aria-expanded="false"
                    >
                      <span className="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                      <span className="icon-bar" />
                      <span className="icon-bar" />
                      <span className="icon-bar" />
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div
                    id="kr-navigation"
                    className="collapse navbar-collapse kr-navigation"
                  >
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <a href="dashboard.html">Dasboard</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </nav>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <header
          id="kr-header"
          className="kr-header cd-auto-hide-header kr-haslayout"
        >
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <strong className="kr-logo">
                  <Link to="/">
                    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="company logo here" />
                  </Link>
                </strong>
                <nav className="kr-addnav">
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <Link
                        id="kr-btnsignin"
                        className="kr-btn kr-btnblue"
                        to="login_register"
                      >
                        <i className="icon-smiling-face" />
                                          <span>{Object.entries(this.state.user).length > 0 ? this.state.user.user.firstname : `-`}</span>
                      </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a
                        className="kr-btn kr-btngreen"
                        href="dashboardaddlisting.html"
                      >
                        <i className="icon-plus" />
                        <span>Add Listing</span>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a onClick={this.logout} className="kr-btn kr-btngreen">
                        <i className="icon-plus" />
                        <span>Logout</span>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </nav>
                <nav id="kr-nav" className="kr-nav">
                  <div className="navbar-header">
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      className="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                      data-toggle="collapse"
                      data-target="#kr-navigation"
                      aria-expanded="false"
                    >
                      <span className="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                      <span className="icon-bar" />
                      <span className="icon-bar" />
                      <span className="icon-bar" />
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div
                    id="kr-navigation"
                    className="collapse navbar-collapse kr-navigation"
                  >
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <a href="dashboard.html">Dasboard</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </nav>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>
      );
    }
  }
}
```